# mysql tell difference between table and view

Tags: mysql

I'm surprised I didn't find this answer out there.

I know very well what the difference between a table and a view is.  BUT..how do I DETERMINE whether a db object is a table or view?  Since

```
show tables;
```

will show both tables and views - and there is no "show views" command.

to determine in my coding (which has to read multiple objects and may not "know" better), I do this:

show create view my_table_or_view

and if I get an error, which I prevent from dying, it's a table.  Pretty clumsy, is there a better way?

Comment: prefix all views with 'v_' when creating them

Comment: I just specified that the coding may not know better (though that's a good idea and i actually do that).  But I don't want to assume.  I could do this it turns out:
    show full tables where Table_Type = 'BASE TABLE'
works well, alternate is to use 'VIEW'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query and if it returns a record it's a table

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE 'TABLE_TYPE' = 'BASE TABLE'
AND table_name = 'your table name'
```

Comment: I assume I can also flip that query to use VIEW instead of BASE TABLE

Answer (score 1):

try this variation instead ...

```
show full tables;
```

the Table_type column will give the info you require  :)